# How to increment to next number

Tags: oracle, numbers, number-formatting

I have a field in my table which is of type NUMBER. It has values like the below,

```
COL1
1
1.1
2
2.111
3
4.5
```

Now I have a request to increment this to the next highest number of the same kind.

If the value is whole, say 1, i need to increment it to 2. If the value is decimal, say 1.1, i need to increment it to 1.2.

Any pointers on how to do it would be greatly helpful.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1107846 might help... looking for something simpler though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on BluShadow Jul 27, 2010 8:55 AM : @ https://community.oracle.com/thread/1107846 ...

Still may be a simpler way, but this seems to work.

```
  select col1, case when floor(col1)=col1 
    then col1+1 
    else power(10,-1*
    regexp_count(regexp_replace(col1,'[0-9]*\.([0-9])','\1'),'[0-9]'))+col1 end as nextNum 
  from (
  select 1  as col1 from dual union all
  Select 1.1 as col1 from dual union all
  select 2 as col1 from dual union all
  select 2.111 as col1 from dual union all
  select 3 as col1 from dual union all
  select 4.5 as col1 from dual) b
```

What this does:
uses a case statement to compare the floor of col1 to col1 (essentially finding out if there are decimals), if not simply add 1.

If there are decimals count how many.  Use the power function and base 10 to identify the correct decimal position to add one to, and and add it back to col1 base.